# How to add multiple arrays into a Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android.I want to add some multiple arrays into the `RecyclerView` and i want to get the data into the RecyclerView from the required URLs. But i don't know how to do that.So if anybody have the solution on this.

Comment: show us how your list look like ?

Comment: In that RecyclerView there will be some TextView's and One ImageView @ Sandy

Comment: so how your multiple array will be used ?

Comment: for one textview one array imageview one array like this,,,

Answer (score 1):

create a bean class and custom array list of bean type like below

my LoginBean.java class

```
public class LoginBean {

    public String phonenumber;
    public String password;
    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }
    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

My aarayList

```
ArrayList<LoginBean> arrayList=new ArrayList<LoginBean>();
```

add element into array list

```
LoginBean lb=new LoginBean();
lb.setPhonenymber("1234");
lb.setPasswor("1234")
arrayList.add(lb);
```

now you can send only this arraylist into recycle view

get data from arraylist into recylce view

```
LoginBean lb=arraylist.get(postion);
testview.settext(lb.getPhonenumber);
```

Comment: Thank u @ vishal jangid